# Unable to drag icons in Dock

Tags: macos, dock

Running Yosemite 10.10.2 (14C109). The icons in the Dock cannot be dragged. When I click on an icon, it darkens, but then moving the mouse simply removes the focus on the icon. I cannot move the icons around, or off of the icon bar.

Things I have tried:
 - killing Dock process
 - deleting/moving preference files
 - restarting

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Parental Controls enabled? "Allow user to modify Dock" is a setting that you might possibly have unchecked if you have them enabled.

Comment: No, this is the main (admin account). And I can remove icons using the context menu, or add them by dragging icons onto the dock. I just can't drag icons around or off the dock.